# Laravel localhost server not working on ios devices

Tags: php, laravel, server, localhost

I host my laravel project using my network ip address and it's working using android phone, but when i use ios device the page is accessed but only blank display.

What is the problem for this situation and how to solve it?

Comment: You need to collect some debug data. Your problem without any technical details can be caused by gazillion different reasons.

Comment: what you are using? ngrok?

Comment: I'm using xampp server btw

Comment: Are you accessing the same port in both scenarios?
Have you connected to the same wi-fi with both devices?

Comment: @NoOorZ24 Yes i can access it, but no display when using iphone, however when im using android it work perfectly.